# Python's foreach backwards

Tags: python, foreach, python-2.4

Does python have a means of doing foreach backwards?  I'm hoping to do a filter() (or list comprehension) and reverse a list at the same time, so that I can avoid doing it separately (which I suspect will be slower).  I'm using python 2.4 (I have to unfortunately), but I'm also curious what the list comprehension solution would be in python 3.0.

**Edit** Both of these solutions appear to be the same:

```
python -m timeit -s 'x=[1,2,3,4,5]*99; filter(lambda x: x == 5, reversed(x))' 
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0117 usec per loop
python -m timeit -s 'x=[1,2,3,4,5]*99; x.reverse(); filter(lambda x: x == 5, x)'    
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0117 usec per loop
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would suspect it would be slower, at least to a point that you should worry about it. This sounds a bit like premature optimization to me.

Comment: It just seemed to me like filter() goes through once and reverse() goes through a 2nd time, so I figured there would be a way to do this with one traversal.

Comment: You could always unroll the two manually, but that won't be faster if written in Python, and the overhead almost certainly (*especially* if you don't have hard data to prove otherwise) isn't worth writing a C extension module. And that's assuming that you write the comparision in C as well, calling back into Python for each item will greatly reduce any potential gain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a good compilation of things you could do to achieve backward iteration: http://christophe-simonis-at-tiny.blogspot.com/2008/08/python-reverse-enumerate.html

Comment: Big +1 for providing a link that explores alternatives.

Comment: -1: It's better to ALSO provide a summary of the linked article, at least. Otherwise if the link goes down, this answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 32):

You are looking for the built-in [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
>>> for i in reversed(range(5)):
...     print i
... 
4
3
2
1
0
```

This iterates over the sequence in reverse, without creating an additional copy of your list.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the right way to do it in the same time with filtering. Just use `reverse`, it will be much more optimized than doing it manually.